# Instance created from snapshot not working at lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a Lightsail instance that is running and working but I needed a clone of that, so I created a snapshot and then created a new instance from that snapshot.

The instances have a node API and a react front end running.

I already tried to start both projects, restart the server and reboot the instance, but I can't make this clone to work. It keeps redirecting me to the bitnami default page.
I tried "node app.js" and pm2, but none of these worked.

I'm new to AWS and Lightsail so I don't know if I'm skipping something here.

Comment: why didnt you try to make an AMI instead of snapshot? Maybe you have more than one volume and the snaphot you are taking is not the right one